FCM Token used for Device token Retrieval Fails on iOS 15 but Works on iOS 17 and Later - React Native
I am working on retrieving the FCM token and my implementation works perfectly on iOS 17. However, when I try the same code on iOS 15, I consistently receive a null value for the device token. Below is the relevant portion of my code. Do I need to change my implementation for lower iOS versions? It feels like this might be related to the App Tracking Transparency (ATT) permission. Any insights on why this might be happening or how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.
const userlogin = async () => {
    const deviceType = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'IOS' : 'ANDROID';
    try {
        let fcmToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fcmToken');

        if (!EMAIL_REGEX.test(email)) {
            showError('Please enter a valid email');
            updateState({ isloading: false });
        } else if (password?.length < 4) {
            if (password?.length < 1) {
                showError('Please enter password');
                updateState({ isloading: false });
            } else {
                showError('Password should be at least 6 characters long');
                updateState({ isloading: false });
            }
        } else {
            let apidata = {
                email: email?.toLowerCase(),
                password: password,
                deviceToken: fcmToken,
                deviceType: deviceType,
            };
            actions.Userlogin(apidata)
                .then((res: any) => {
                    if (!res?.isProfileSetup && res?.tagsId?.length > 0) {
                        navigation.navigate(navigationString.PRESONALIZESCREEN, {
                            userData: res,
                        });
                        updateState({ isloading: false });
                    } else if (
                        (!res?.isProfileSetup && res?.tagsId?.length === 0) ||
                        res?.tagsId?.length === undefined
                    ) {
                        navigation.navigate(navigationString.HOBBIESSCREEN);
                        updateState({ isloading: false });
                    } else {
                        updateState({ isloading: false });
                        // showSuccess('Welcome!');
                    }
                    console.log(res, 'User has successfully logged in');
                })
                .catch((err: any) => {
                    if (err?.data) showError(err?.data);
                    updateState({ isloading: false });
                });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        updateState({ isloading: false });
        console.log(error, 'Error in user login');
    }
};

    const getFcmToken = async () => {
  try {
    let fcmToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fcmToken');
    console.log(fcmToken, 'the old token');

    await messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages();

    // Check if the token is null, undefined, or an empty string
    if (!fcmToken || fcmToken === null || fcmToken === '') {
      console.log('No FCM token found, generating a new one...');

      // Now get the FCM token
      fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
      if (fcmToken) {
        console.log(fcmToken, 'the newly generated token');
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('fcmToken', fcmToken);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error, 'error in retrieving or generating FCM token');
  }
};
export async function requestUserPermission() {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
        authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
        authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

    if (enabled) {
        console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
        getFcmToken();
    }
}

this is the error we are getting
 [Error: [messaging/unknown] The operation couldn’t be completed. No APNS token specified before fetching FCM Token] error in retrieving or generating FCM token

So that means getFcmToken is getting called but no value is set.

Where is the code that stores the token?

Hi, we store it in our userS model in the DB . With Ios 17, our frontend can generate the appropriate fcmtoken : device token and send the appropriate request body . But in IOS 15 OR  lower IOS we get the value as null .I cant figure it out why its happening.
I am thinking of an approach where if I cant generate the device token , I might just generate a random string and set it as a device token . But I am worried it might break the push notification service

My point is you have shown the code that fetches the token, but if it is giving you null the obvious conclusion is that the token wasn't stored. You need to show the code that stores the token when iOS provides it. You can't just create some random value.

let fcmToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fcmToken');
This returns null for devices with OS 15 or lower. We are getting null value when fetching. It means react-native inbuilt function is not giving us the token for those particular devices. Do you think it could be something to do with push notification and its allowance to retrieve such tokens?

That is just getting a value from AsyncStorage. Something needs to have put it in AsyncStorage first.

const getFcmToken = async () => {
let fcmToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fcmToken');
console.log(fcmToken, 'the old token');
if (!fcmToken) {
try {
const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
if (fcmToken) {
console.log(fcmToken, 'the new genrated token');
await AsyncStorage.setItem('fcmToken', fcmToken);
}
} catch (error) {
console.log(error, 'error in fcmToken');
}
}
}; This is the code I guess that sets the value

[edit] your question to include relevant code in a code block and indicated what debugging you have done. What console messages are printed? Is this code actually called?

I have added both of the codes and changed my questions

The error message seems to indicate that you have not called the relevant registration function in the messaging package you are using.
